# Google Maps v3 load partially on top left corner, resize event does not work

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google Maps V3 loaded partially on top left corner. I tried the following methods:

- Add `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` after map initialization.
- Rearrange `<script>` tag in index file

But none works for me. How to solve this issue. Is there an official bug and solution to this issue?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap, from LayoutIt!</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Bootstrap css files -->
    <link href="stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="stylesheets/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="contentbar">
      <div id="dashboard-content" class="contentbar-main">
        Some Content
      </div>
      <div id="summary-content" class="contentbar-main" style="display:none;">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
              <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span7" id="sidebarid">
                  <p>Responsive web design is an approach, I often call it a mindset, because you have to change the way you think when you're going responsive. The basic idea behind it is: one design to rule them all - no m.domain.com, no touch.domain.com, no 3 separate CSS files, no 7 PSD files for each device or each orientation - just “domain.com” looking the same on desktop, tablet and phone.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="span5" id="contentbarid">
                  <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span12">
                      <input type="button" value="toggle" id="toggle-button">
                      <div id="map-canvas" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span12">
                      <p>Responsive web design is an approach, I often call it a mindset, because you have to change the way you think when you're going responsive. The basic idea behind it is: one design to rule them all - no m.domain.com, no touch.domain.com, no 3 separate CSS files, no 7 PSD files for each device or each orientation - just “domain.com” looking the same on desktop, tablet and phone.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- jQuery scripts -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Bootstrap script -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <!-- My basic script file-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/my-script.js"></script>
      <!--Google Map server url-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAngjBDpe4ep15u5dvlnbZbn1ghA5uISZY&sensor=false"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

**my-script.js**

```
var map;
$(document).ready(function(){
  google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
    initializeMap();
});

//Load Map in Summary Tab
function initializeMap() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
}
```

Comment: As proper indenting shows, you are missing one closing `</div>` tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps Not Working in jQuery Tabs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458215/google-maps-not-working-in-jquery-tabs)

Comment: Please could you update the code with the final solution? I am in the same issue and nothing works for me. Thank you much

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I've had this issue before too and fixed it by waiting for the map's 'idle' state (i.e. when it's finished) and then calling the resize:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
   google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
});
```

Comment: That's not the same thing though, as you call your initializeMap() function when jQuery has decided the map is ready, not the map API itself.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. I had the same issue and tried to fire the resize even manually like this `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` triggered by a viewport resize. Unfortunately this did not solve the issue; only the solution above solved it.

Comment: @IanDevlin I was struggling with this all day until I found this. Thanks!! I'm curious if you can briefly explain why this is sometimes necessary. I've used it without the event listener many times in the past without problems, so I want to understand better.

Comment: Oh man!  Thanks!  I've been searching for a while and tried so many things.  This did it.

Comment: Complementing: if you're using jQuery mobile, it would be better to create the map in the `pageshow` event. This code worked only inside this event listener, not inside `pagecreate`

Comment: You're a king! Thanks. +1

Comment: Moving a map from Leaflet to Google Maps I replaced window.map.invalidateSize(); with the above code. Worked beautifully. +1

Comment: Tried this but not works +1, but `window.setTimeout(function(){
       google.maps.event.trigger(window.mainmap, 'resize');
      }, 2000);` works, I was confused.

Comment: Recreate my map using `window.mainmap = new google.maps.Map(dom, mapProperty);` and then bind idle event, then it works.

Answer (score 10):

I think your map is hidden at the time you create it: there's a `display:none` on the `#summary-content` div that the map is nested inside.

You should try triggering the `resize` event *after* that div is made visible instead of during initialization.

In fact, you could probably just call your `initializeMap()` function event at the time that div is made visible, instead of calling it in your `.ready()` function.

Comment: Yes at first my #summary-content div is invisible,after click on navigation item the #summary-content will visible. I added resize event in onclick event of #summary-content.It works fine. But I dont need to load map every time navigating between pages.

Comment: Initialising the map when making the element visible is what worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I had the issue with all maps other than the first loaded map showing in the top left corner with the rest of the map having not loaded and therefore showing in grey.

Was scratching my head for some time but managed to solve it with:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
       google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
       map.setCenter(latLng);
    });
```

It was a easy solution  thanks to Ian Devlin and d.raev and just wanted to say thanks and share the code that solved it for me seeing as I can't comment or vote up yet!

I called that after creating the map with:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("business-location-"+business_username), map_options);
```

so if you've got this problem put it right under where you create your **map** too!

Comment: All the solution above didn't worked for me except this. Thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

Google Maps does not play well with Bootstrap. Try adding the following CSS to your map element

```
#map-canvas img {
  max-width: none;
}
```

[Twitter Bootstrap CSS affecting Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141249/twitter-bootstrap-css-affecting-google-maps)

Comment: Change CSS selector to "#map-canvas img".

Comment: no it does not works.As Mr.Michael Geary said,my div is not visible when map load. I try to trigger resize event when my div is visible.But it also not works.

Comment: This code works. You have to change the css selectors to match your code.

Answer (score 1):

I just got a similar issue  (map loaded in container expanded with animation)

As @Ian Devlin part of the solution is, is to trigger `resize` event after all is visible.
The second part is to fix the center (as it is usually in the top left corner):

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
   google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
   map.setCenter(center); // var center = new google.maps.LatLng(50,3,10.9);
});
```

Comment: this was the only solution to work for me (google map in an invisible modal)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a relatively old question now however, I have come across this issue today and found a resolution. It may (may not) be helpful to people, however if you require to show the Google Maps onclick then if you call your ***initilise()*** function within this event and delay it as seen from my code below.

***Google Maps API function - initialise();***

```
var locationLondon = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850);
var map;    

    function initialise(location){
        //Object to define properties
        var mapProp = {
            center: locationLondon,
            zoom: 15,
            disableDefaultUI:true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

        //Map Marker
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: locationLondon,
            map: map
        });

        marker.setMap(map);
    };
```

***My jQuery event call***

```
    $( document ).ready(function(){
        $( '#maps-container' ).hide();
        $( '#card-1 .fa-info-circle' ).click(function(event){
            event.stopPropagation();
            $( '#maps-container' ).delay( 1000 ).fadeIn( 'slow' );
            $( '#map-load' ).delay( 1000 ).fadeOut( 'slow' );
            setTimeout(initialise, 1000);
        });
    });
```

- *'#map-load'* is a preloader screen for the map's initial load
- *'#maps-container'* is the container for the Google Map (#googleMap)

Answer (score 0):

Use pageshow event with the shown format. It worked for me.

$(document).on('pageshow', '[data-role="page"]#mapPage' , function(){
initialize();
});