# want to load multiple google maps with loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps

i am using a php while loop to create a div class multiple times

so every time i have different lat lng

also in every loop i initialize a new map on a different div to create the map
and here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

            function initialize() {

                var title= "Title";
                var lat = <?php echo $lat; ?>;
                var lng = <?php echo $lng; ?>;
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 14,
                    center: myLatlng
                  }
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('beezMapBig<?php echo $tmp;?>'), mapOptions);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      position: myLatlng,
                      map: map,
                      title: 'Hello World!'
                    });
                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
                    var center = map.getCenter();
                    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
                    map.setCenter(center); 
                }); 

            }


          </script>
```

everytime the load works with the different lat,lng but i dont have the map 100% loaded
(i cant post image due to low reputation...imagine that the map is loading like 50% with the rest grey blank)

now the weird part is that when i press f12 at any browser to run the console to see some problems/failures the map is getting 100% loaded and resized.

Any ideas why this occurs and why the code is running correctly when run the browser console??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059816/google-maps-v3-load-partially-on-top-left-corner-resize-event-does-not-work

Comment: What sets the size of the "map" divs?  Do you really have multiple functions named "initialize"?

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue and solved by doing this.
write `ready()` function. and then place the window resize functions in the initialize method itself (before initializing the map). It will help.

Comment: Write $(document).ready() function first, then put your (window, 'resize') function before the map initializing. do some arrangements in code.. ll work.. you done almost all.

Comment: it cant work beacause i am using a while loop....so document ready function is running only 1 time....

Comment: no.. use doc.ready fn() after the loop. STEP:1--doc.ready fn()
STEP:2--your loop
STEP:3--initializing()
STEP:4--(window, 'resize') function()
STEP:5--map initializing fn()

like this

Answer (score 0):

I can use PHP and JS. I have array with 3 elements.

Firstly Im generating div with unique id

```
   <?php $i=0; foreach ($array as $single) : $i++; ?>

      <div id="map_<?php echo $i; ?>" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"></div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Then im opening script tag like this

```
 <script>
    var maps = [];
    <?php $i = 0; foreach($array as $single): $i++; ?>
    maps.push({
      mapContainer: 'map_'+<?php echo $i; ?>,
      lat: <?php echo $single['mapa_google']['lat']; ?>,
      lng: <?php echo $single['mapa_google']['lng']; ?>,
    });
    <?php endforeach; ?>

   function initMap() {
     for(var i = 0; i < maps.length; i++)
     {
       // The location of Uluru
       var uluru = {lat: maps[i].lat, lng: maps[i].lng};
       // The map, centered at Uluru
       var map = new google.maps.Map(
         document.getElementById(maps[i].mapContainer), {zoom: 16, center: uluru}
       );
       // The marker, positioned at Uluru
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});
     }
   }
 </script>
```

On the bottom on my page im using async script

```
   <script async defer
           src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOURKEY&callback=initMap">
   </script>
```

Of course in my array I have data for 3 google maps.