# google maps resize event

Tags: jquery, google-maps

The problem is start the map hidden, if the toggle buttom start showing the map there isn't any ploblem.

I'm seeing a lot of question with this problem but I can't fix it. This is my code. I call the resize event after toogle the map and doen't work.

```
$('.map-btn').click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggle(500, function(){
        var gMap = document.getElementById("acf-map");
        google.maps.event.trigger(gMap, 'resize'); 
    });
})
```

Related question here [Google Maps v3 load partially on top left corner, resize event does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059816/google-maps-v3-load-partially-on-top-left-corner-resize-event-does-not-work/33876461#33876461)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Form my experience is better recall a (re)initilizeMap() function when you click the tab for show the map.

Due the problem/difficulties related to the correct congfiguration of the map in this case if you, wher click the tab for show the map call the initializzazion of the map. the problem is structurally solved.